# How to set Value of the union Range?

Tags: excel, vsto

I have a union Range, combined from multiple cells spread across the workbook. Is it possible to assign new values to all cells of this Range at once?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to assign the same value to all cells in the union range, something like this would work:

```
Union(Range("A1"), Range("A3"), Range("C64434")).Value = 3.14159
```

Comment: I always was sure that "values" is plural form.

Comment: I see. "assign new value_s_" is crazy difficult to understand.

Comment: If you give an example of what you want to do and tell us what you've tried it would be helpful.